# Passing more than 22 columns to a UDF in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a UDF written in my Spark Java code in which I want to pass more than 22 columns(exactly 24). But the Spark API allows only max of 22 columns, any tricks to override this or can I create custom UDF function to override this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass column of complex type. The most general solution is a Struct but you can consider Array or Map as well.

Parameters in a Map Example:

```
    val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","b"),("c","d"), 
      ("e","f"))).toDF("one","two")


     val myUDF = udf((input:Map[String,String]) => {
      // do something with the input
       input("one")=="a"
       })

     df
    .withColumn("udf_args",map(
       lit("one"),$"one",
        lit("two"),$"one"
      )
    )
    .withColumn("udf_result", myUDF($"udf_args"))
     .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing 24 column values, You can pass array of column values to the udf and the operations will be on the array.
Here is the sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

case class department(id: Integer, deptname: String)
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq(department(1, "physics")
      , department(2, "computer")).toDF()
val df2 = df1.withColumn("all_col", array($"id", $"deptname"))
val concat_udf:UserDefinedFunction = udf((all_col_values:Seq[String]) => {
      (all_col_values(0) + "-" + all_col_values(1))
    })
//apply udf
val df3 = df2.withColumn("all_col_concat",concat_udf(col("all_col")))
df3.show()
```

**Extra:**
If it's possible to apply anonymous functions on each row without udf, you can try this way but not sure whether it'll fulfill the requirement or not.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val df4 = df1.rdd.map{ case Row(id:Integer, deptname:String) => (id, deptname,id.toString()+"-"+deptname)}.
          toDF("id","deptname", "all_col_concat")
df4.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of answers are written in scala, as you asked in spark java I will rewrite it in Java. The answer can be used in an arbitrary number of columns as well.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array;

List<Column> cols =  Arrays.asList(new Column[] {ds.select("col1"), ds.select("col2") ...});// all the columns
Column mergedCol = array(cols.toArray(new Column[cols.size()])); //merge all your cols
//udf
UserDefinedFunction myUdf = udf(
    (Seq<Object> seq) -> {
        //you should have 24 Objects here. 
        for (Object o : JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(seq).asJava()) {                  
                ...         
        );
    },
    DataTypes.[your data type]);
//use it as
ds.select(myUdf.apply(mergedCol));
```